# Why does my storyboard that is within a DataTemplate not begin?

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, datatemplate

I have a custom drawn 'Path' control with some texblocks inside making up a DataTemplate in Silverlight 4. I used the Animation window in Expression Blend to create a simple animation that I can 'play' and see work OK within Blend.

I want this animation to fire off on the '_MouseEnter()' event (VB.NET) I want to issue a .Begin method on the animation. Seems straight forward enough.

However at runtime nothing happens. I place a breakpoint on the _MouseEnter event and surely enough it goes into the event upon the mouse entering the control, it runs the line of code to begin animation but nothing happens. No exception, no animation, nothing.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing here since I know the actual animation *does* work, it just is not running at runtime? XAML and event are below (removed some styling properties on Texblocks, etc. to make easier to read):

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyItemTemplate">
        <Grid Width="50"  Height="80" Opacity="0.9"
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" 
            ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding ItemName}">            

            <Grid.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Name="MyItemTemplateAnimate">
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[4].(GradientStop.Offset)" 
                            Storyboard.TargetName="path">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0.296"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="0.384"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0.475"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="0.529"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="0.587"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="0.652"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.9" Value="0.582"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0.523"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.1" Value="0.5"/>
                    /DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </Grid.Resources>

            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform Rotation="180"/>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>

            <Path x:Name="path" Data="M 0,0 L 50,0 50,50 25,80 0,50 0,0" Stroke="Wheat" StrokeThickness="2">
                <Path.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="-0.419,0.662" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="1.051,-0.137">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF250A0A" Offset="1"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF250A0A"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF501616" Offset="0.725"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF501616" Offset="0.275"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF9F4C4C" Offset="0.5"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Path.Fill>
            </Path>

            <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock1"                              
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock2"
            </TextBlock>                                    
        </Grid> 
    </DataTemplate>
```

The code that uses the DataTemplate:

```
<m:MapItemsControl x:Name="MyItems" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyItemTemplate}"/>
```

And here is the VB.NET event:

```
Private Sub MyItems_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs) Handles MyItems.MouseEnter                  

      MyItemTemplateAnimate.Begin()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it figured out:

**Begin StoryBoard Animation Within A DataTemplate In Silverlight:**
http://allen-conway-dotnet.blogspot.com/2011/09/begin-storyboard-animation-within.html

Answer (score 0):

Since your storyboard is in an ItemTemplate there is going to be one storyboard per item. So I'm not sure why you're not getting an exception, but I believe this is a name scope issue.

If your animation is on the individual items why not start it when the mouse goes over the item itself instead of the itemscontrol?

Comment: My control naming might sound confusing, but they are *not* within an 'ItemTemplate' but rather a 'DataTemplate'. To answer your 2nd question, the path object within the DataTemplate itself does not have any events exposed in the code. Only the DataTemplate itself exposes the events like: 'MouseEnter'. The path does not expose those properties.

Answer (score 0):

Is the storyboards TargetProperty correct, because there you are using GradientBrush but in your path you have LinearGradientBrush. Just a wild guess. :)